# Import cannot be resolved when library is already in build path

Tags: eclipse, import

I'm having an issue where I'm getting a red error message "Import cannot be resolved" when the library in question is already on the build path.  I cannot add it again to the build path, and removing it and adding it again does not resolve the issue.

[image]

The commons library was directly downloaded from apache.  I'm very confused and unsure what else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it is in the lib directory does not mean that it is on your buildpath.

Right-click on the library and see whether it says `add to build-path`

Comment: thanks, that seems to have done it.  The funny thing is I imported it as a user library and it still didn't like it.